# Typescript and react - Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

So I have object in typescript used in react components that has this type:

```
export type DataInfoTypes<dataType> = {
  data: dataType | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: boolean;
};
```

Let's assume that "dataType" there would be (should not matter, just an object of strings):

```
{[key in string]: string}
```

Then when I use this data in React component, I check if object.data is not null:

```
if (!materials.data || materials.loading) {
  return <DataLoading />;
}
```

Then in my return function, when I reference data it seems okay:

```
<Flex alignItems="center" direction="column">
  <Text>{materials.data["somekey"]}</Text>
  <VStack w="100%" ....
```

However few lines down I have an array map method(in same component, same return):

```
<VStack w="100%" align="center">
  {sources.map((matKey: string, index: number) => {
    return <Text key={index}>{materials.data["somekey"]}</Text>
  }
</VStack>
```

And I get this error:

> Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

Any ideas on how to fix this or what is the cause?
(Please exclude all the tsignore solutions if possible)
Big thanks to everyone responding.

Comment: what object is possibly null? materials.data["somekey"]?

Comment: just materials.data

Answer (score 1):

The declared type of `data` is `dataType` or `null`. What the ts compiler is telling you is that you are trying to access a property (`.someKey`) of a possibly `null` value, which will result into a runtime error.

To fix it, use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
materials.data?.somekey
```

which will return the value of `data.somekey` when `data` is not `null` and `undefined` when `data` is `null`.

Most importantly, optional chaining does not throw a runtime error when `data` is falsy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand what you are saying, but I have a condition before the return statement, that does check if materials.data is not null, so therefore it should be just "dataType" inside the return statement. It also shows no problem when it is inside top-level JSX tags, but when I use materials.data inside array.map function , then the problem occurs.